# How do we get the output when 1 filter convolutes over 3 images?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

Imagine, that I have a 28 x 28 size grayscale image.. Now if I apply a Keras Convolutional layer with 3 filters and 3X3 size with 1X1 stride, I will get 3 images as output. Now if I again apply a Keras Convolutional layer with only 1 filter and 3X3 size and 1X1 stride, so how will this one 3X3 filter convolute over these 3 images and then how will we get one image..

What I think is that, the one filter will convolute over each of the 3 images resulting in 3 images, then it adds all of the three images to get the one output image.

I am using tensorflow backend of keras. please excuse my grammar, And Please Help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:

I figured out that the one filter convolutes over 3 images, it results in 3 images, but then these these images pixel values are added together to get one resultant image..

You can indeed check by outputting 3 images for 3 filters on 1 image. when you add these 3 images yourself (matrix addition), and plot it, the resultant image makes a lot of sense.